# Android cannot capture image and show as thumbnail

Tags: android

```
    OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fileName = "Camera_Example.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                        "Image capture by camera");

                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);



            }
        };




    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start ****************/

                    String imageId = convertImageUriToFile(imageUri, CameraActivity);

                    // Create and excecute AsyncTask to load capture image

                    new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute("" + imageId);

                    /*********** Load Captured Image And Data End ****************/

                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }





public class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        Bitmap mBitmap;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            /****** NOTE: You can call UI Element here. *****/

            // Progress Dialog
            Dialog.setMessage(" Loading image from Sdcard..");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Bitmap newBitmap = null;
            Uri uri = null;

            try {

                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                                + urls[0]);

                /************** Decode an input stream into a bitmap. *********/
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(uri));

                if (bitmap != null) {

                    /********* Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap. ***********/

                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 350, 350,
                            true);
                    // SaveIamge(newBitmap);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    if (newBitmap != null) {

                        mBitmap = newBitmap;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Error fetching image, try to recover

                /********* Cancel execution of this task. **********/
                cancel(true);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (mBitmap != null) {

                showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have written Above code to capture image and display as a thumbnail.It works perfectly in android tab 2 and huwawi tab.but when i try it on TAb 3 it gives following error,Can you help me to avoid this Error.

```
11-18 10:16:04.882: E/AndroidRuntime(7289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.cap_im/com.example.cap_im.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.cap_im/com.example.cap_im.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 10:16:04.882: E/AndroidRuntime(7289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
```